# What if give the name of existing gmail as an alias to the outlook mail?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, gmail, alias

Let's say I have mymail@**gmail.com**. What if I'll set mymail@**gmail.com** as an alias for mymail@**outlook.com**? If somebody will sent me mail to **gmail.com**, will I get the message on the **outlook.com**?
What if left mymail@**gmail.com** as an ailas of outlook, but delete the real **gmail.com** account? Will I still get mails sent by people to mymail@**gmail.com**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the alias will only work for logging in to Microsoft services but not for email delivery.

A mail system cannot "claim" a foreign address for itself. As long as DNS MX records at `gmail.com` point to Gmail servers, all mail sent to `anything@gmail.com` will go to those Gmail servers – no exceptions.